# How to update Azure App Configuration Settings using Code (.Net Core)

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, appsettings, azure-configuration

I have an `Azure` app registered on Azure portal which is created in `.NET Core 2.0` This app reads some config value from the **`Application settings`** section from the portal as shown in below image.
[image]

Now at some stage I want to update those config value from code. I have searched for many article but not found how to update Azure **`Application settings`** from code. Can any one have an idea or suggestion that How can I update Azure **`Application settings`** using `.NET Core 2.0 C#`?

Comment: Could you solve it with provided solution?

Answer (score 3):

This can be accomplished using [Azure.ApplicationModel.Configuration](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.ApplicationModel.Configuration/) nuget package.
In particular, the [SetConfigurationSetting](https://azuresdkdocs.blob.core.windows.net/$web/dotnet/Azure.Data.AppConfiguration/1.0.0/api/index.html#update-an-existing-configuration-setting) method seems to do what you are after.

```
string connectionString = "<connection_string>";
var client = new ConfigurationClient(connectionString);
ConfigurationSetting setting = client.SetConfigurationSetting("some_key","new_value");
```

Note: This package is in preview

Comment: This works only for Configuration Store I think. Or there is a way to use it with existing web app Application settings? What is connection_string for it then?

Comment: @arteny For the connection string, inject `IConfiguration`, then, assuming you've followed the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/quickstart-aspnet-core-app?tabs=core5x#connect-to-the-app-configuration-store), you can use `configuration.GetConnectionString("AppConfig")`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use c# to call the REST API [`Web Apps - Update Application Settings`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/WebApps/UpdateApplicationSettings) manually.

```
PUT https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{name}/config/appsettings?api-version=2019-08-01
```

For more details about how to call Azure REST API in c#, you could refer to this [link](http://blog.davidebbo.com/2015/12/calling-arm-using-plain-rest.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use c# to do it, you could try with `Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent` package, the below is the sample code, you could have a try.

```
            string tenantId = "*******";
            string clientSecret = "********";
            string clientId = "********";
            string subscriptionId = "*******";

            var azureCredentials = new AzureCredentials(new
              ServicePrincipalLoginInformation
            {
                       ClientId = clientId,
                       ClientSecret=clientSecret
            }, tenantId, AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud) ;
            var _azure = Azure
           .Configure()
           .WithLogLevel(HttpLoggingDelegatingHandler.Level.Basic)
           .Authenticate(azureCredentials)
           .WithSubscription(subscriptionId);

            var appResourceId = "/subscriptions/**********/resourcegroups/*******/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/***"; //Get From WebApp -> Properties -> Resource ID

            var webapp = _azure.WebApps.GetById(appResourceId);

            webapp.Update()
                .WithAppSetting("test", "testvalue")
                .Apply();
```

Comment: Hi George, I have tried your code, it gave me an exception (Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden') , what should I do to solve it

Comment: Did you ever solve you 'Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden' problem? I've run into the same problem

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work, and as the other two posters have suggested that this produces a 403 forbidden response.

Answer (score 0):

The library has been changed to Azure.Data.AppConfiguration.
Azure.ApplicationModel.Configuration is depracated

Answer (score 0):

This is an addendum to George Chen's answer.

To avoid the "Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden' exception after calling _azure.WebApps.GetById(appResourceId), you need to ensure the service principal associated with the Azure Credential has contributor access to the subscription the web app is in. For more details refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal.